# Сохранение шаблона в переменную в не шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Есть некоторый код

```
template<class T>
struct EventLink {
    T* cl;
    (T::* func)();
};
class EventFunction {
    // Здесь переменная, которая хранит в себе EventLink
    public:
    template <class T>
    void add(T* Class, void (T::* func)()) {
        // здесь код сохранения аргументов в EventLink
    }
};
```

В общем я хочу создавать объекты класса EventFunction, не являющимся шаблонным, но при этом чтобы была возможность передать и сохранить класс и привязанную к нему функцию через шаблонную функцию add. При этом эти аргументы должны сохраняться в структуру EventLink. Дело в том, что я пишу систему событий, и мне нужно на одно и то же событие навешивать функции из разных классов, поэтому пытаюсь так тупо сохранить их. Надеюсь, что я правильно описал, в чём моя проблема ( Сам найти решение так и не смог ). Если мой способ невозможно реализовать - пожалуйста, напишите, как можно сделать это по-другому.

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, то вы хотите хранить в **не** шаблонном классе некоторое количество данных заранее не известных типов?

Comment: Harry, типа того

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY. Такое ощущение, что вам на самом деле надо хранить некоторый коллбек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такое устроит?

```
#include <any>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct EventLink
{
    EventLink(T*cl,void (T::* func)()):cl(cl),func(func){}
    T* cl;
    void (T::* func)();
};

class EventFunction {
    any a;
    // Здесь переменная, которая хранит в себе EventLink
    public:
    template <class T>
    void add(T* Class, void (T::* func)()) {
        a = EventLink{Class, func};
    }
};

struct Z
{
    void x(){};
};

int main()
{
    EventFunction ev;
    Z z;
    ev.add(&z,&Z::x);
}
```

Comment: Возможно я тупой, но у меня что-то пошло не так и на any a; ругается Visual Studio ( идентификатор не определён у any )

Comment: Какой версии? У меня VC++ 2017 (15.9.19) спокойно съел...

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Еще вариант - ключик стандарта (`/std:`) какой? Ну, или какая версия C++ в настройках проекта выставлена?

Comment: Не совсем понял, это как? Где посмотреть? Если я правильно понял, то стандарт C++ выставлен по умолчанию, а какой там по умолчанию - я не знаю

Comment: Проект-свойства-С/С++-Язык-Стандарт языка С++

Comment: Поставил стандарт c++ на c++17 и он воспринял any как класс, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Краткая справка по `any`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: Вроде то, что нужно. Я только не смог разобраться, как из a можно достать теперь данные? ( Не используя шаблонов при этом, потому что второй функции неизвестно, какой класс и какая функция там хранится )

Comment: А как же вы хотите получить то, не знаю что?... С++ язык строго типизируемый. Запоминайте как-то типы при внесении. Посмотрите, нельзя ли их сделать производными от одного общего типа - это тоже может облегчить решение (тогда вообще не нужны шаблоны, храните указатель на базовый тип, например, и все).